# LiveValidation plugin - HTML in failureMessage

Tags: html, livevalidation

I am using the  [LiveValidation plugin](http://livevalidation.com/examples) and was wondering of there is a way to add HTML in the span tags that show a valid or invalid message. I have the following:

```
var validatedObj = new LiveValidation('momlastname', { validMessage: ""});
validatedObj.add(Validate.Presence,{ failureMessage: "You need a name in this <strong>field</strong>"});
```

But when I test the code I get this:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5mRP.jpg)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Danijel. I modified the function as follows:

```
createMessageSpan: function () {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = this.message;
            return span;
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not implemented, `failureMessage` parameter is treated as string. Here is function that creates message ( [source](https://github.com/alechill/livevalidation/blob/master/src/livevalidation_standalone.js) ), so you can change that:

```
createMessageSpan: function(){
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(this.message);
    span.appendChild(textNode);
    return span;
},
```

It is also possible to override `onValid` and `onInvalid` default callbacks, and to impliment your own functionality. Check the official [documentation](http://livevalidation.com/documentation#LiveValidationConstructor) for more info.